# Convexity of a set of probability distributions

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, optimal-transport

Let $Q = $ {$d$-dimensional probability distributions with independent marginals from the [exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family)}, i.e.
$$Q = \left\{ q(x) = \prod_{i=1}^d q_i(x_i), q_i = a(x) \exp\{\eta(\theta)T(\theta)+a(\theta)\} \;\;  \big| \;\; x\in \mathbb{R}^d\right\}.$$

I'm wondering if this is convex in the ambient space $(P(\mathbb{R}^d), W_2)$ (probability distributions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with 2-Wasserstein distance.).

I believe the exponential family of measures is a convex set in $(P(\mathbb{R}^d), W_2)$ -- is this true? Anyways, I think that $Q$ here is a product of such sets.

A set $A$ is geodesically convex iff the geodesic between every two points in $A$ is contained in $A$. Since the ambient space here is $(P(\mathbb{R}^d), W_2)$, the geodesics between points are really optimal transport plans between them. So the convexity question comes down to "For $p,q\in Q$, does the optimal transport plan between $p$ and $q$ send mass only between marginals, $p_i$ to $q_i$?" I have no idea if this is true or how to prove/disprove it.

**edit: one idea I had:** since the intersection of convex sets is convex, and $Q$ is the intersection of probability spaces on $\mathbb{R}^d$ where the $i$th component is independent of all others, $$ Q = \cap_{i=1}^d A_i \;\;\;\; \text{ where } A_i = \{q = q_i(x_i)q_{-i}(x_{-i})\}$$ where the subscript $-i$ indicates "all componentx except $i$". This space $A_i$ is the cartesian product of two convex spaces $\{q_i(x_i) \in P(\mathbb{R})\}$ and $\{q_{-i}(x_i) \in P(\mathbb{R}^{d-1})$ so it is convex.

Does this argument hold?

**edit** literally any thoughts are welcome. No complete answers are needed or expected!

Comment: It is not clear to me from your question if you mean _convex_ or _geodesically convex_. $P_2(\mathbb R^d)$ is a convex set in the linear space of bounded measures on $\mathbb R^d$ so $A\subset P_2(\mathbb R^d)$ can be convex in the usual sense ($\theta \mu+(1-\theta)\nu \in A$ for $\mu,\nu\in A$, $\theta\in [0,1]$). On the other hand you define _geodesic convexity_ and claim that $A$ is convex iff geodesically so. Do you mean this is by definition (if so, it could be clarified), or that each and every (linearly) convex set is $W_2$-geodesically convex (which is not true)?

Comment: @AlephBeth I suppose I'm asking if $Q$ is geodesically convex (the answer someone gave shows that it is not convex) and have edited my question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Let $O_1 := (0,1)$ and $O_2 := (1,2)$.
Then,
$q_1(x) = \chi_{O_1}(x_1) \chi_{O_1}(x_2)$
and
$q_2(x) = \chi_{O_2}(x_1) \chi_{O_2}(x_2)$
belong to $Q$,
but their midpoint does not belong to $Q$.

Comment: Hi @gerw! Thanks for your answer but coming back to this question, it's not clear what you mean by "midpoint". (It should be midpoint of the geodesic in $W_2$ space, but then it's not clear to me that this does not belong to $Q$).

Comment: With midpoint I mean $(q_1 + q_2)/2$, i.e., just the algebraic midpoint. If $Q$ would be convex, then this point would belong to $Q$ again. Or do you have another definition of convexity of $Q$ in mind?

Comment: since the ambient space is wrt the 2-wasserstein distance, I would think that the "line segment" between two points is actually the geodesic in $W_2$ distance (see updated question)