# Projection of a measure wrt Wasserstein distance

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, optimization, projection, optimal-transport

If we start with an arbitrary $n$-dimensional probability distribution, $\mu$, I am interested in the projection, with respect to the 2-Wasserstein distance, onto the set of product distributions $$Q = \{ \nu: \nu(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n \nu_i(x_i), \int_\mathbb{R} \nu_i(x_i) dx_i = 1, \text{ for } x\in \mathbb{R}^n\}$$

i.e. $Q$ is the set of distributions with its distribution on each component independent of all others.

For any given measure $\mu$, one way to get a sort of corresponding measure in $Q$ is to take the product of all the marginals of $\mu$ (basically ignoring any dependence), $\prod_{i=1}^n \mu(x_i)$. But I would specifically like to get a projection wrt $W_2$ distance,

$$ \text{Proj}_Q(\mu) = \arg\min_{q \in Q} W_2(q, \mu)^2 $$

More specifically, it might be helpful to specify the form of $\mu$: a simple example could be that $\mu$ is a $n$-dimensional Gaussian, and we want the projection onto $n$ independent 1-d Gaussians $q_i(x_i)$. Or, more generally, $\mu$ is an $n$-dimensional [exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family), and we want the projection onto $n$ independent 1-d exponential families.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: You're hoping for a closed form solution? I know first-order algorithms that are applicable after you rewrite the problem and semidualize the Wassterstein distance (with entropic regularization).

Comment: @TSF a closed form solution would be nice, or at least some intuition. I'll specify in the question some more constraints on the type of distribution $\mu$.

Comment: @TSF what kind of algorithms would those be?

Comment: See Chapter 5.4.3 in this phd thesis https://hal.inria.fr/THESES-NU/tel-03201840v1 The entropically regularized wasserstein inverse problem is a general problem that encompasses what you've written here. The regularizer in your case is the indicator function of the set $Q$.

Comment: @tsf thanks, I'm looking at it now: I'm a bit confused. so the entropically regularized wasserstein problem wants the transport plan $p$ sending $\mu$ to $q$ (both fixed), minimizing $\int C(x,y) p(dx dy) + \int p \log p$. My problem  on the other hand wants to find the optimal $q$. Do you mean the objective fucntion is replaced by $\int C(x,y) p(dx dy) + I_Q(p)$? (where $I_Q(p)$ is 0 if the destination $q$ is a product distribution) and $\infty$ otherwise)

Comment: @TSF I.e. sorry but I don't understand the connection between their problem and mine)

Comment: You are correct about what is the entropically regularized Wasserstein distance. If you look at the problem they actually solve, its equation (5.4.4):  $\min\limits_{\rho} W_\gamma (F\rho,\theta)+J\circ A(\rho)$ where $\theta$ is the observed measure and $W_\gamma$ the entropically regularized Was distance. In this problem, if we take $J\circ A(\rho) = I_Q(\rho)$ and $F=\mathrm{Id}$ then we have exactly the problem you're looking at but with $W_\gamma$ instead of $W$ (entropically regularized Wasserstein distance instead of the ordinary one): $\min\limits_{\rho\in Q} W_\gamma (\rho,\theta)$.

Comment: @TSF I understand, thanks! Can the constraint $q\in Q$ also be described using entropy/mutual information? From the paper you shared, it seems $Q$ can be expressed as the set of measures $q$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $h(q) = \sum_{i=1}^n q(x_i)$. I asked a related question here (if you don't mind me sharing) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4175599/convexity-of-a-set-of-probability-distributions

Comment: ^Since measures in $Q$ have 0 mutual information, the inequality $h(q) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n h(q_i)$ where $q_i = q(x_i)$ is the $i$th marginal, and equality holds if mutual information is 0

Comment: Based on the concepts presented in https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.07278, I think that the projection into $Q$ of a measure $\mu$ with marginals $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ is not, as I previously believed, $\mu_1\otimes\mu_2$. (Essentially, using the factorization thought a pivot measure, one could show that one of the marginals can be "improved" by choosing the barycenter of the disintegrations of the privot measure.)

Comment: It has been nearly 10 months since the last comment: Did anything come of this? This same (and quite interesting, IMO) projection problem came up in recent investigations of mine, and I'm wondering if you found any literature, description of optimizer(s), applications, etc.

Comment: @Dan sadly no, and I've been working on other things recently. But I'm interested to hear what your project is about.

Comment: Noted, that's too bad. I will post an update here if/when my investigations lead anywhere relevant...